# mysql - Using COUNT() as total AND WHERE with a JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have tried several statements but cant seem to get the results I need. Here is what I have so far, but this produces an empty table.

I need to count the amount of `word_id` there are in the `wordnik_examples` table that are less than 20 within a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT wordnik_examples.word_id,wordnik_word.word,count(wordnik_examples.word_id) as total
FROM `wordnik_examples`
JOIN `wordnik_word` ON wordnik_examples.word_id = wordnik_word.ID
WHERE (SELECT count(wordnik_examples.word_id) FROM `wordnik_examples`) < 20
GROUP BY wordnik_examples.word_id ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

I also have tried

```
SELECT wordnik_examples.word_id,wordnik_word.word,count(wordnik_examples.word_id) as total
FROM `wordnik_examples`
JOIN `wordnik_word` ON wordnik_examples.word_id = wordnik_word.ID
WHERE total < 20
GROUP BY wordnik_examples.word_id ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

But the mysql comes back with an error saying that the `total` column us unknown.

I also tried using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` with both queries and that did not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not grouping deeply enough. If you have two "regular" columns followed by an aggregate, group by the two "regular" columns. MySQL is rare in letting you get away with only grouping by a subset of the non-aggregate columns.

As for filtering by any aggregate, which here means the count, you must using `HAVING`.

```
SELECT
  wordnik_examples.word_id,
  wordnik_word.word,
  count(wordnik_examples.word_id) as total
FROM wordnik_examples
JOIN wordnik_word ON wordnik_examples.word_id = wordnik_word.ID
GROUP BY
  wordnik_examples.word_id,
  wordnik_word.word
HAVING count(wordnik_examples.word_id) < 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to do a join and count the number of instance where wordnik_examples.word_id is less then 20. You were assigning total to be a bunch of collumns, and then trying to check the data. 
Try this -

SELECT wordnik_examples.word_id,wordnik_word.word,count(wordnik_examples.word_id)
FROM `wordnik_examples`
JOIN `wordnik_word` ON wordnik_examples.word_id = wordnik_word.ID
WHERE wordnik_examples.word_id < 20
GROUP BY wordnik_examples.word_id ORDER BY `total` DESC